# How to Ensure Imported Keys Are Non-Exportable in TPM 2.0?

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, tpm, tpm-2.0

I'm working with TPM 2.0 and have successfully imported an RSA key into the TPM using the tpm2_import command. I've followed the process to create a primary key, generate an RSA key using OpenSSL, import it into TPM, load it, and then make it persistent using the tpm2_evictcontrol command. Here's a brief overview of the steps I took:

Generated an RSA key using OpenSSL:
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem

Created a primary key in the TPM:
sudo tpm2_createprimary -C e -g sha256 -G rsa -c primary.ctx

Imported the OpenSSL-generated RSA key into TPM:
sudo tpm2_import -C primary.ctx -G rsa -i private_key.pem -u pub.blob -r priv.blob

Loaded the imported key into TPM and made it persistent:
sudo tpm2_load -C primary.ctx -u pub.blob -r priv.blob -c loaded_key.ctx
sudo tpm2_evictcontrol -C o -c loaded_key.ctx 0x81000002

Checked the public portion of the persistent key:
sudo tpm2_readpublic -c 0x81000002

Output:
name: 000b28ab86c4a706c2f3870e90147a2b282f853bebfc4e0977714e95932d5b62995d
qualified name: 000bb96e10e635cb9b26fae628dc6fcb451d8cc5c20e736b5cf1390ba7aef934d834
name-alg:
value: sha256
raw: 0xb
attributes:
value: userwithauth|decrypt|sign
raw: 0x60040
type:
value: rsa
raw: 0x1
exponent: 65537
bits: 2048
scheme:
value: null
raw: 0x10
scheme-halg:
value: (null)
raw: 0x0
sym-alg:
value: null
raw: 0x10
sym-mode:
value: (null)
raw: 0x0
sym-keybits: 0
rsa: 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

The persistent key has attributes userwithauth|decrypt|sign, which I believe means it can still be exported out of TPM.

My question is: Is there a way to import a key into TPM such that it becomes non-exportable? I want to ensure that once a key is loaded into TPM, it cannot be extracted or exported out. I'm relatively new to TPM 2.0, so any guidance or clarification on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

I tried specifying -a "fixedtpm|fixedparent|sensitivedataorigin|userwithauth|decrypt" during the import, expecting these attributes to enforce non-exportability, but this didn't work as anticipated. Am I going in the wrong direction with this? Any advice or guidance on how to correctly accomplish this would be highly appreciated. I'm seeking to understand the correct method or set of commands to ensure the key, once loaded into the TPM, cannot be extracted.